# Is there support for an easy install of the runtime on a Suse Linux Enterprise Server 12?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are running SLES 12 servers. I wanted to install the Azure Iot Edge Runtime on our machines. So far there is no easy way (rpm package). Are there plans to add support for OpenSuse and SLES 12 SP2?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases

Answer (score 3):

You can find platform support for Azure IoT Edge here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support

If your platform is not listed there, you can nevertheless try and install Azure IoT Edge Runtime and report issues here: https://github.com/azure/iotedge/issues .

I would also suggest that you fill a new feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find one approach to build and install the IoT Edge runtime on SLES 12 from https://github.com/vjrantal/iotedge-suse-build.

The approach in that repository is to build the .rpm packages of the runtime using Docker and then use zypper to install those packages to the target host based on SLES 12.

Comment: Elobarate ur answer

Comment: I edited to elaborate what the approach in the linked repository is and hopefully that makes it more clear how the repository relates to the original question.